# Transactions within the Node's API CRUD callback (Drupal)

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

Should I call the db_transaction() inside the node's CRUD hook (like hook_load, hook_insert, etc)?

UPD: The crux of the matter is, for example, the hook_update and hook_insert functions are called from the node_save(), and it's code is already wrapped in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

If you're performing multiple queries and want the option to rollback on failure of one of them then yes. It's safe to do so as each `db_transaction` goes out of scope when the function it's in is finished running, so you should never be in a position where you're starting a new transaction while another one is already open so to speak.

Comment: It's true. But the crux of the matter is, for example, the hook_update and hook_insert functions are called from the node_save(), and it's code is already wrapped in a transaction.

Comment: In that case, you definitely shouldn't call `db_transaction` from your hook function...there would be no point. The `try...catch` block in `node_save` will roll back the entire transaction (including any queries you've executed in your hook functions) if an exception is raised at any point, so creating a separate transaction is not required

Comment: Note that Drupal supports nesting transactions, so you can theoretically do it. But yes, the existing transaction started by node_save() will already deal with the rollback when something goes wrong. There are however reasons for starting nested transactions, basically if you want to be able to revert your changes only (as opposed to all changes related to the node save.)